# Helix 3d-toolkit Displayed .STL model color change

Tags: helix-3d-toolkit

Im making an c# application that display a 3dmodel.stl in a windows form.

I've managed to display it but the default color for the model is blue and i need to change it to anything else, lets say pink/brown (it should look like skin).

I've been 2 days looking for it and reading documentation and examples but i have not found a way to change it.

If someone has worked whit helix and know how (or even if there is a way) to do it i'will thanks him so much for the info.

the code is very simple:

XAML code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Ventana.Visor3D"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:helix="http://helix-toolkit.org/wpf"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Ventana"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <helix:HelixViewport3D x:Name="viewPort3d" ZoomExtentsWhenLoaded="true" Grid.RowSpan="2" >

        <helix:SunLight/>
    </helix:HelixViewport3D>
</Grid>
```

And the C# code:

```
public partial class Visor3D : UserControl
{
    private const string MODEL_PATH = "\\Prueba.STL";
    ModelVisual3D device3D;

    public Visor3D(){ }

    public void Carga() {

        InitializeComponent();
        device3D = new ModelVisual3D();  
        device3D.Content = Display3d(MODEL_PATH);  

        viewPort3d.Children.Add(device3D);            
 }



    private Model3D Display3d(string model)
    {
        Model3D device = null;
        try
        {

            viewPort3d.RotateGesture = new MouseGesture(MouseAction.LeftClick);


            ModelImporter import = new ModelImporter();


            device = import.Load(Environment.CurrentDirectory + model);                
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {               
            MessageBox.Show("Exception Error : " + e.StackTrace);
        }
        return device;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi,Iam also stuck with the same prob.Do you have the prop solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the same problem with *.obj* file with *helix* toolkit. My solution was to replace the `Material` of object with new one. Isn't the best solution I guess, but it works on my WPF Project.

```
// Set your RGB Color on the SolitColorBrush
System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Material mat = MaterialHelper.CreateMaterial(
            new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255))

//Replace myModel3DGroup by your Model3DGroup of your view....
foreach (System.Windows.Media.Media3D.GeometryModel3D geometryModel in myModel3DGroup.Children)
{
    geometryModel.Material = mat;
    geometryModel.BackMaterial = mat;
}
```

Comment: Thx for the help! the problem is that .STL does not have the property.Material, so i cant change it